# Are there built-in primitives for interactions in Feature tools?

Tags: featuretools

are there built-in primitives performing absolute and relative differences between two numeric columns? Two date columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can currently be done for numeric columns, but not datetimes.

With interaction terms, we typically recommend you manually define the specific features you want. For example, here is how to define difference and absolute difference between to numeric features

```
import featuretools as ft

es = ft.demo.load_retail(nrows=1000)

total = ft.Feature(es["order_products"]["total"])
unit_price = ft.Feature(es["order_products"]["unit_price"])

difference = unit_price - total
absolute_diff = abs(difference)

fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features=[difference, absolute_diff], entityset=es)
fm.head()
```

this returns

```
                  unit_price - total  ABSOLUTE(unit_price - total)
order_product_id                                                  
0                           -21.0375                       21.0375
1                           -27.9675                       27.9675
2                           -31.7625                       31.7625
3                           -27.9675                       27.9675
4                           -27.9675                       27.9675
```

We could also pass those values those values to `ft.dfs` as [seed features](https://docs.featuretools.com/guides/tuning_dfs.html#using-seed-features) if we wanted other primitives to stack on top of them.